# What's the difference between res.redirect and res.sendfile?

Tags: javascript, express

I completed a tutorial challenge of setting up a 'failure' page and a 'Try again' button. The button takes the user back to '/signup/html'. I used

```
app.post("/failure", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});
```

But the tutorial used the `res.redirect` method.

The result is the same, but what's happening in the background, are there any differences using
`res.redirect` and `res.sendFile`?

Thanks,

Comment: The [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) for those methods will tell you what they are doing exactly (and therefor differently) - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it, [`redirect`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) issues a redirect but [`sendFile`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) sends a file.

I'm going to assume that code elsewhere responds to whatever path the tutorial said to use with `redirect` (let's say `/signin`) by sending that same file. So it might seem the same, but there are important differences:

1. Using `redirect` means you're only specifying that filename in one place, not two, which is better for maintenance.
2. If there's middleware set up on the other route (`/signin` or whatever), that middleware will get run with a `redirect` but not with your code.
3. `redirect` sends a message back to the browser telling it to request the other URL; your code sends the file directly.
4. With `redirect`, you can specify the `redirect` HTTP status code to use, for instance if you wanted to tell the client that the redirection is permanent (by specifying status code `302`, though in your example that probably wouldn't be appropriate).